# I can't connect a asp.net login database in visual studio express 2013 for web

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am adding a login to an asp.net website so it creates a database to store the info for that, but this database doesn't connect to the server it says that I have to upgrade the server from version 655 to version 706, how do I do that upgrade?

Comment: How could we?, we have literally no idea what you are doing or any details whatsoever

Comment: I'm afraid there is not enough information here to help you. Do you have a code snippet (a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) of your trying to connect? Is there a log on the server side?